# How to set number of trees in Weka's Java library (setNumTrees no longer works?)

Tags: java, weka

Using the Java Weka library I need to set the number of trees.

I found a [nice example,](http://www.codemiles.com/weka-examples/weka-java-code-for-random-forest-cross-validation-t11128.html) but it seems that this method

```
    RandomForest rf = new RandomForest();
    rf.setNumTrees(100);
```

no longer works and I don't see any substitute for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SetNumIteration` instead of `SetNumTrees`.

Comment: Thanks. I am not where I can test/research this at the moment, so I will take your word for it. I will verify it next chance I get.